# Why is there a lot of extra files installed with npm i?

Tags: node.js, npm

The installation is standard.

```
npm init
npm i -D
```

Why are .cmd, .ps1 files added ?

[image]

Is this correct?

I watch examples of videos on YouTube, everywhere a clean installation.
I have Windows 10, node.js 14.17.0
I tried reinstalling node.js but it didn't help 
It turns out to be the same with cmd. The Ide is not to blame

Comment: One thing you could do is look at them, e.g., `ps1` files are likely PowerShell scripts. `cmd` files are likely batch scripts. The ones w/o extensions are likely standard shell scripts. Can you delete them? Sure. Should you? Only you know. I mean, you deliberately installed the CLI tools, so it seems like you wanted them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have studied the problem. It turns out to be the same with cmd. The Ide is not to blame

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to delete these file. These files are used as command line helper files so that your commands like `npx webpack` or `npm run dev` (where `"dev": "webpack"` in your package.json) can run.

Generally, these files are present inside the `<project_dir>/node_modules/.bin` folder after **webpack** and **webpack-cli** installation. The NPM installation itself will never generate these files at the root of your project. Check the `.bin` folder if these files are present there. If not, copy it back to that folder.

The possible reason why this could have happened is that your editor or one of its plugin might have accidentally copies/moved these files from `node_modules/.bin` directory.

- `webpack` and `webpack.cli` - Used by Linux/Mac Terminal
- `webpack.cmd` and `webpack-cli.cmd` - Used by Windows Console
- `webpack.ps1` and `webpack-cli.ps1` - Used by Windows Powershell

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have studied the problem. It turns out to be the same with cmd. The Ide is not to blame

Comment: I install 16.2.0 Current, and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Extra files are created only on `node-v14. 17. 0-x64` 
On `node-v16. 2. 0-x64`, a clean installation is created without unnecessary files